# ValidationObj not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I am trying to validate a form using jquery validation and I keep receiving an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined".

The error is coming from the jquery-latest.min.js file and my jquery.validate.min.js file. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Also, when I remove validationObj.form(); block, the error goes away, but then the validation rules are not running.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="contactForm">
  <p>Contact Information</p></br>
    <div id="contactInfo">
        <label>First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="fName" id="fName"/></br>

        <label>Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="lName" id="lName"/></br>

        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/></br>

        <label>Phone:</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"/></br>
    </div></br>
```

And here is my js:

```
var validationObj = $("#contactForm").validate
        (
            {
                rules:
                    {
                        fName:{required:true},
                        lName:{required:true},
                        email:{required:true, email:true},
                    },//End rules
                messages:
                    {
                        fName:{equalTo:"Please enter your first name"},
                        lName:{equalTo:"Please enter your last name"},
                        email:{minlength:"Please enter a valid email"},
                    },//End messages

                errorPlacement:
                    function(error, element)
                        {
                            error.appendTo( element.next());
                        }
            }//End validationObj
        );//End var validationObj

validationObj.form();
    $("form").submit
        (function(e)
            {
                if(!validationObj.form())
                {
                    alert("Form Errors");
                }
            }
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapped it in a form and removed the call before the submit. Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ndoes/5w3j4jrx/).

```
var validationObj = $("#contactForm").validate({
    rules: {
      fName: {
        required: true
      },
      lName: {
        required: true
      },
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
    }, //End rules
    messages: {
      fName: {
        equalTo: "Please enter your first name"
      },
      lName: {
        equalTo: "Please enter your last name"
      },
      email: {
        minlength: "Please enter a valid email"
      },
    }, //End messages
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      error.appendTo(element.next());
    }
  } //End validationObj
); //End var validationObj

$("#contactForm").submit(function(e) {
  if (!validationObj.form()) {
    alert("Form Errors");
  } else {
    alert("Form Valid");
  }
});
```